Which is the correct approach to use supabase + nextjs + toast
I've tried using supabase docs to create a component but I'm having issues with Sever Side Components and Client Side Components. This is my Login Component
export default async function Login() {
  const supabase = createClient();
  const { data: user } = await supabase.auth.getUser();

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleLogin = async (formData: FormData) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      await login(formData);
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("Login failed!");
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  };
  return (
    <main className="h-full w-full flex flex-col justify-between items-center pt-56 pb-24 z-20 relative ">
      <h1 className="font-NAM text-white text-9xl">title</h1>
      <form className="flex flex-col w-80">
        <Input
          name="email"
          className="mb-5"
          fullWidth
          placeholder="Email"
          type="text"
        />
        <div className="w-full mb-5">
          <Input
            name="password"
            className="mb-1"
            fullWidth
            placeholder="Password"
            type="password"
          />
          <div className="flex justify-between text-white underline text-sm">
            <Link className="hover:text-white" href="/register">
              Regístrate
            </Link>
            <Link className="hover:text-white" href="/">
              Olvidaste tu contraseña?
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Button formAction={handleLogin} uppercase={true} filled={true}>
          Inicia sesión
        </Button>
      </form>
    </main>
  );
}

Which is the correct approach to not have the problem with use client and use server?

you definitely need to use server-side component for that.

Issue is that you've declared an async component, which means it's always meant to run on the server. Thus in it, you're not allowed to use client-side hooks and methods, such as useState.
